# Upload CSV File and Parse data to Array in Grails?

Tags: parsing, grails, csv, upload

I have created a view with browse button to let the user select a file and then when they click the Upload button it should fire that function in the controller.

I have setup the View and the Controller with the empty function and I have been looking at "[Grails CSV Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/csv)" to aid in parsing the file but from the usage information I cant seem to grasp how I can get this CSV data into an array?

Can any1 please help me with this?? Thanks in advance

This is my Controller which is basically empty:

```
package com.smstool

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

class UploadController {

    def index() {
        redirect(action: "upload", params: params)
    }

    def upload() {

        }

}
```

And my view simply contains this form:

```
<g:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <label for="file">File:</label>  
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>  
            <input class="save" type="submit" value="Upload"/>  
        </g:form>
```

I just tried this in the controller:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

class UploadController {

    def index() {
        redirect(action: "upload", params: params)
    }

    def upload() {


        }


    def batchUpload() {

            def csv = new File('file')

            //def csv = '''Name,Lastname
            //Mark,Andersson
            //Pete,Hansen'''

            def data = parseCsv(csv)

            for(line in data) {
                println "$line.Number"
            }
    }



}
```

This did not work as I get the following error, any ideas?

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /upload/batchUpload
Class
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
    No signature of method: static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [file] Possible solutions: parseCsv(java.io.Reader), parseCsv(java.lang.String), parseCsv(java.util.Map, java.io.Reader), parseCsv(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String)

Around line 28 of grails-app/controllers/com/tool/UploadController.groovy

25:         //Mark,Andersson26:         //Pete,Hansen'''27:         28:         def data = parseCsv(csv)29:         30:         for(line in data) {31:              println "$line.Number"

Around line 195 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java

192:            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {193:             log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",194:                     new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });195:               chain.doFilter(request, response);196:              return;197:         }198:

Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java

60:     try {61:            // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping62:         if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {63:                doFilter(request, response, chain);64:          }65:            else {66:               chain.doFilter(req, res);

Trace

    Line | Method
->>   28 | batchUpload in UploadController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    195 | doFilter    in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter .  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1110 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run         in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 3):

View:

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Controller, with the Grails CSV plugin installed:

```
def upload() {
    def file = request.getFile('file')
    def allLines = file.inputStream.toCsvReader().readAll()
    ...
}
```

Comment: This did work and the information was stored. I have 3 rows of data with headers, and I only need to get the data for 1 row and store it into an array, how can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

To read a single line or first line:

```
def upload() {
   def file = request.getFile('file')
   def aLine = file.inputStream.toCsvReader().readNext()
   ...
}
```